# Plotting each value of columns for a specific row

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am struggling to plot a specific row from a dataframe. Below is the Graph i am trying to plot. I have tried using ggplot and normal plot but i cannot figure it out.

[image: This is the output I'm am trying to plot]

```
 Wt2 Wt3 Wt4 Wt5 Lngth2 Lngth3 Lngth4 Lngth5
1  48  59  95  82    141    157    168    183
2  59  68 102 102    140    168    174    170
3  61  77  93 107    145    162    172    177
4  54  43 104 104    146    159    176    171
5 100 145 185 247    150    158    168    175
6  68  82  95 118    142    140    178    189
7  68  95 109 111    139    171    176    175
```

Above is the Data frame I am trying to plot with. The rows are for each bears measurement. So row 1 is for bear 1. How would I plot only the Wt columns for bear 1 against an X-axis that goes from years 2 to 5

Comment: Another thing, it is more useful to post the data in a way we can run code with, so the next time post the output of `dput(your_data_frame)` instead of the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pivot your data frame into a longer format:

First add a column with the row number (bear number):

```
df = cbind("Bear"=as.factor(1:nrow(df)), df)
```

It needs to be factor so we can pass it as a group variable to ggplot. Now pivot:

```
df2 = tidyr::pivot_longer(df[,1:5], cols=2:5,
                          names_to="Year", values_to="Weight", names_prefix="Wt")
df2$Year = as.numeric(df2$Year)
```

We ignore the Length columns with `df[,1:5]`; say that we only want to pivot the weight columns with `df[,2:5]`; then say the name of the columns we want to create with `names_to` and `values_to`; and lastly the `names_prefix="Wt"` removes the "Wt" before the column names, leaving only the year number, but we get a character, so we need to make it numeric with `as.numeric()`.

Then plot:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=Year, y=Weight, linetype=Bear)) + geom_line()
```

Output (Ps: i created my own data, so the actual numbers are off):

[image]

Just an addition, if you don't want to specify the columns of your dataset explicity, you can do:

```
df2 = df2[,grep("Wt|Bear", colnames(df)]
df2 = tidyr::pivot_longer(df2, cols=grep("Wt", colnames(df2)),
                          names_to="Year", values_to="Weight", names_prefix="Wt")
```

**Edit: one plot for each group**

You can use `facet_wrap`:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=Year, y=Weight, linetype=Bear)) +
  facet_wrap(~Bear, nrow=2, ncol=4) +
  geom_line()
```

Output:

[image]

You can change the `nrow` and `ncol` as you wish, and can remove the `linetype` from `aes()` as you already have a differenciation, but it's not mandatory.

You can also change the levels of the categorical data to make the labels on each graph better, do `levels(df2$Bear) = paste("Bear", 1:7)` for example (or do that the when creating it).

Comment: Thank you so much! Just one more question. Where in ggplot do we specify the factor variable? Is the the linetype part?

Comment: Yes! You can also use different aesthetics to differentiate the bears, such as `color=Bear`, `alpha=Bear` (transparency), etc... If it solved your problem, remember to accept the answer :)

Comment: Sorry one last question, how would one then create 7 different plots for each factor variable?

Comment: Just a clarification on my comment above for each level of the factor variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = seq.int(2, 5), y = c(48, 59, 95, 82))) +
  geom_point(color = "blue") +
  geom_line(color = "blue") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Weight")
```

Comment: In general, if you need to plot a specific row of a data frame, it would be helpful to have an id column. Most R plotting libraries will have functions with some sort of "by = " argument for group plotting.