# How to plot a specific row in a dataframe using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that shows the number of car sales in each country for years 2000 to 2020. I wish to plot a line graph to show how the number of car sales have changed over time for only a specific country/row, with year on the x axis and sales on the y axis. How would I do this using ggplot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting each value of columns for a specific row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66723799/plotting-each-value-of-columns-for-a-specific-row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You perhaps want this

```r
#toy_data
sales
#>   Country 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010
#> 2       A 1002  976  746  147 1207  627  157 1481 1885 1908  392
#> 3       B  846  723 1935  176 1083  636 1540 1692  899  607 1446
#> 4       C 1858  139 1250  121 1520  199  864  238 1109 1029  937
#> 5       D  534 1203 1759  553 1765 1784 1410  420  606  467 1391

library(tidyverse)
#for all countries
sales %>% pivot_longer(!Country, names_to = 'year', values_to = 'sales') %>%
  mutate(year = as.numeric(year)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = sales, color = Country)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

```r
#for one country
sales %>% pivot_longer(!Country, names_to = 'year', values_to = 'sales') %>%
  mutate(year = as.numeric(year)) %>%
  filter(Country == 'A') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = sales)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a data frame that looks like this:

```
#make dummy df
df <- matrix(sample(1:100, 63), ncol=21, nrow=3)
rownames(df) <- c("UK", "US", "UAE")
colnames(df) <- 2000:2020
```

Here I generated some random data for 21 years between 2000 and 2020, and for three countries. To get a line plot with ggplot for UK, I did:

```
data_uk <- data.frame(year=colnames(df), sales=df["UK",], row.names=NULL)
ggplot(data=data_uk, aes(x=year, y=sales, group=1)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[Example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNSxE.png)

Comment: For more flexibility, instead of creating data_uk you could also just do `new_df = as.data.frame(t(df))`. Then in ggplot, you can say `x=UK` or `x=UAE`. Just faster to change and less code to write.